# SQL Server: how to optimize "like" queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query that searches for clients using "like" with wildcard. For example:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
       [t0].[CLIENTNUMBER], 
       [t0].[FIRSTNAME], 
       [t0].[LASTNAME], 
       [t0].[MI], 
       [t0].[MDOCNUMBER]
  FROM [dbo].[CLIENT] AS [t0]
 WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM([t0].[DOCREVNO])) = '0') 
   AND ([t0].[FIRSTNAME] LIKE '%John%') 
   AND ([t0].[LASTNAME] LIKE '%Smith%') 
   AND ([t0].[SSN] LIKE '%123%') 
   AND ([t0].[CLIENTNUMBER] LIKE '%123%') 
   AND ([t0].[MDOCNUMBER] LIKE '%123%') 
   AND ([t0].[CLIENTINDICATOR] = 'ON')
```

It can also use less parameters in "where" clause, for example:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
       [t0].[CLIENTNUMBER], 
       [t0].[FIRSTNAME], 
       [t0].[LASTNAME], 
       [t0].[MI], 
       [t0].[MDOCNUMBER]
  FROM [dbo].[CLIENT] AS [t0]
 WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM([t0].[DOCREVNO])) = '0') 
   AND ([t0].[FIRSTNAME] LIKE '%John%') 
   AND ([t0].[CLIENTINDICATOR] = 'ON')
```

Can anybody tell what is the best way to optimize performance of such query? Maybe I need to create an index? This table can have up to 1000K records in production.

Comment: Index will not help you if you use `LIKE`. And why do you need to optimize: do you already have performance issue?

Comment: Indexes cannot help you with values that start with wildcards, i.e. they will help you with values like `John%` but **not** `%John%`

Comment: If you are using LINQ, and can switch from `Contains` to `StartsWith`, SQL Server will be able to use an index.

Comment: @gabe: this is the same as Vlad's comment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do much for a `LIKE` where the pattern has the form `'%XXX%'`, you want to look up SQL Server's full-text indexing capability, and use `CONTAINS` instead of `LIKE`. As-is, you're doing a full table scan, because a normal index won't help with a search for an item that starts with a wild card -- but a full-text index will.

```
/* ... */
 WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM([t0].[DOCREVNO])) = '0') 
   AND (contains([t0].[FIRSTNAME], 'John')) 
   AND (contains([t0].[LASTNAME], 'Smith')) 
   AND (contains([t0].[SSN], '123'))
   AND (contains([t0].[CLIENTNUMBER],'123')) 
   AND (contains([t0].[MDOCNUMBER], '123')) 
   AND ([t0].[CLIENTINDICATOR] = 'ON')
```

Comment: Will that find a person whose SSN is `567-89-0123`?

Comment: +1, except you don't make it clear whether full-text indices are updated on a schedule (asynchronously) as opposed to "on insert/update/delete" (synchronously.)

Comment: @Gabe - Assuming the other filter criteria are true, yes. It will also find 123-45-6789, 678-90-1234 and even 012-34-5678 if the SSN is stored without the dashes.

Comment: @Jerry, thanks for the answer. I will try this. Just wondering how can I tell LINQ to use CONTAINS instead of LIKE?

Comment: FTI can only do prefix query wildcards (EG "top*") and cannot help with the reverse (eg "*top"). so using FTI for the OP won't help.  (Got burned by this today).

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy: if you search for `like '*top'`, you're not using FTI at all, you're using SQL Server's normal searching, and yes it'll do a full table scan. If, however, you use `contains(whatever, 'top')`, that will use FTI (and will find those records quickly). If you need only records that end in `top`, you can then search through that set of records to verify which actually end in 'top' (and given its presumably much smaller size, that's normally fairly fast).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like some databases (PostgreSQL 7.1+, MySQL v3.23.23+, Microsoft-SQL v???, ) already contains such things:

```
MySQL>> ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(body, title);
MySQL>> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('PHP')
```




```
MS-SQL>> SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE FREETEXT (ProductName, 'spread' )
```




```
PgSQL>> CREATE FUNCTION fti() RETURNS opaque AS '/path/to/fti.so' LANGUAGE 'C';
PgSQL>> CREATE TABLE articles_fti (string type, id oid);
....
```


[Oracle...](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/asplund-textsearch.html), [Sybase...](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/verity/@Generic__BookTextView/669;pt=669;lang=uk#X)

Comment: Just to add to MSSQL: approach changed between 2005 and 2008 https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Comment: The way to optimize this in PG is to use trigram indexes, unless you need full text for other reasons.

Comment: @jpmc26, thank you for heads up. As I understand you refer to [`pg_trgrm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgtrgm.html) that is supported since 9.4, that were released in 2014 (4 years later after my response). But thank you for down-vote to attract my attention. Though I still not sure if you wanted to highlight that answer was not useful or that it was not updated.

Comment: @ony The supported/unsupported portion of that page is referring to the versions of PG that are being actively maintained or not. The feature was introduced very long before 9.4. It goes back to at least 8.3 (released in 2008), as can be seen by the available documentation.

Comment: @jpmc26, I found https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/230744 . And now I suspect your comment were completely unrelated to voting. Though my answer refers to same solution as accepted answer it lacks in way information is conveyed  and assumes that reader will follow the leads. Sorry for harsh follow-up discussion in comments. I think both trigrams and FTI valid sub-text lookup. As per my speculation I would expect that for FTI it might be possible to follow index longer than with trigram since it builds all suffixes rather than limits to 3 alphanum characters.

Comment: @ony I was the one who downvoted, and I did so for multiple reasons. The first is that this is a SQL Server question, meaning other DBs are not applicable. The second is that much of the PG info is very outdated or wrong. Full text is the wrong approach here since it does "fuzzy" matching by default, which is not equivalent to `LIKE` queries. Trigrams optimize `LIKE` queries directly, even infix ones. They also don't limit the query to 3 characters; they just use 3 character blocks to optimize the search and (if I understand correctly) use multiple blocks in a single query.

Comment: @jpmc26, AFAIK normal tree-based indexes allows you to perform prefix search producing range of candidate entries. FTI is just another tree-based index that produces all suffix combinations that allows to plan index lookup also starting from arbitrary position in a word and thus allows *infix* lookup. I'm not really familiar with trigram, but in documentation it says "We can measure the similarity of two strings by counting the number of trigrams they share. This simple idea turns out to be very effective for measuring the similarity of words in many natural languages." which seems "fuzzy" :)

Comment: @ony "By counting the number of trigrams that they share." They have to share exact trigrams to be considered for a match. A `LIKE` query with a trigram index in PG will use the trigram index to identify *possible* matches and then perform a full `LIKE` check to confirm before including it in the result. In other words, a trigram index is just used for narrowing the rows that need a full check. So there's no fuzzy matching in terms of the actual result set. Full text search, though, does stemming by design, unless you explicitly use the `simple` dictionary.

Comment: @jpmc26, and what makes you think that FTI will not do the same after filtering some set of rows like trigram did, but using suffixes instead of trigrams? In wiki link that I provided "works by recording all possible suffixes of the words it indexes" and example "Sydney, 'ydney', 'dney', 'ney' and 'ey' stored". Actual query should define final set of rows but not index itself which might be ignored if not suitable. You may want to suggest correction to that wiki because it doesn't match what you say. Note that I think suffix-based index is less suitable for fuzzy matching than trigram-based.

Comment: Read-me in [`contrib/fulltextindex`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/REL8_1_STABLE/contrib/fulltextindex) states the same as that wiki. Apparently implementation was really slow and in 8.2 it was dropped in favor of `tsearch`. They definitely need update for wiki.