# Speed up SQL Server WHERE x LIKE '%blah%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: how to optimize “like” queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532075/sql-server-how-to-optimize-like-queries)

I have to do searching on a database where the WHERE clause looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%blah%'
```

This does a table scan as expected, which makes it slow. Is there a different way to write the query that would make it faster? An index I could put on it, perhaps? Other ideas?

Comment: [Full text indexing.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)

Comment: You need to enable [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Comment: Since you're searching with a `..LIKE '%blah%'` you make it **impossible** for SQL Server to use any kind of index (except the full-text index). So other than using fulltext indexing, there's really no way to speed this up - other than **not** doing it (using `... LIKE 'blah%'` instead - no leading `%`)