# Alternative way to Optimize LIKE statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to perform the following operation:

```
select * from customer_details
where
Case When @LicenseNo != '' Then  dbo.customer_details.LicenseNo Else '' End LIKE  
'%' + @LicenseNo + '%'             
And Case When @EmailAddress = '' Then '' Else dbo.customer_details.ContactEmail End  LIKE  
'%'+  @EmailAddress+ '%'
```

This is a Dynamic query executed from the Stored Procedure.
While using LIKE operator Query execution will be very slow.
How to Optimise this type of query?

> Email Address column have "NULL" values and also more than one record with same email address. So I can't create Full-text Index.
>
> Is there any alternative way to optimize this type of query

Comment: How many rows would you expect to return from this query?

Comment: You don't have much choice to optimize the query other than by using full text search.

Comment: I'd question the notion that this operation actually "needs" to be performed. It hardly seems relevant to allow `LIKE` queries for email addresses. These are typically correct as a whole or they are not; it's not usually desirable to allow queries for (say) `.com` to find just about every email address there is, or assume that `johndoe@provider1.com` must be the one we're looking for just because `jonniedoe@provider2.com` chose a different address.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532075/sql-server-how-to-optimize-like-queries

Comment: 2 to 3 Rows only. But it will take 11sec to Execute the query. We are using this for POS.

Comment: Why do you need a leading wildcard here? Are you sotirng multiple email addresses in  single column?

Comment: what is your requirement? I am assuming the requirement is that if `search parameter` is blank then fetch everything otherwise apply the `search parameter`. If this is correct then why you need `LIKE` operator?

Comment: Yes, correct.
This query used inside the Stored Procedure, 
In Parameter, we pass part of email eg:."demo" Then it should bring this record "demo@gmail.com" 
Otherwise parameter pass empty then bring all the rows

Comment: I think you can create index to optimize your query running time on both fields which are being used in where clause.

Comment: A `like` condition with a leading wildcard could benefit from an index _scan_, particularly if the table has wide rows. It won't be able to use an index _seek_. A [memory-optimized table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Full-text search would be the best option. It *may* be possible to improve the query if you can split it into 4 smaller queries, and only execute the "expensive" ones if you really need to. You would need to use procedural logic for this in a stored procedure, rather than have a single query.

The idea is that you execute the "cheapest" queries first, and return immediately if you get the results your business logic dictates; if you don't get results, you execute the next cheapest query, and so on. Depending on your data, this *may* save you from running expensive "catch all" queries.

I don't have access to SQL Server right now, so can't write the actual proc, but it would be something like:

```
if @LicenseNo != '' and @EmailAddress != ''
  @result = select * from customer_details 
  where LicenseNo LIKE  @LicenseNo + '%'
  and   EmailAddress like @EmailAddress + '%'
  if %result 
    return %result
  else
    @result = select * from customer_details 
    where LicenseNo LIKE  '%' + @LicenseNo + '%'
    and   EmailAddress like @EmailAddress + '%'
    if %result 
      return
    end
   else
    @result = select * from customer_details 
    where LicenseNo LIKE  '%' + @LicenseNo + '%'
    and   EmailAddress like '%' + @EmailAddress + '%'
    if %result 
      return
    end
end
```